# PL/SQL - Simple trigger, take from one column and IF-THEN-ELSE to another column

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, triggers

I am trying to figure out where I am going wrong on this simple trigger. I am quite new to triggers and trying to get used to using them with IFTTT statements.

I want the trigger to watch for a new row entry, and if the value is within a certain range within a column (`col_a`) it will then enter a certain value in the same row, but different column (`col_b`), which will be `NULL` up until this is entered. Please can you help?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_test
BEFORE INSERT
    ON test_table 
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.col_a >= 10
    THEN :new.col_b := 'High';   
  ELSE
    :new.col_b := 'Low';
  END IF;
END;
```

It just keeps coming back with "success with compilation error".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this using a virtual column:

```
alter table test_table
    add col_b generated always as (case when col_a >= 10 then 'High' else 'Low' end);
```

I wish that exercises in triggers used reasonable use-cases.  This is not one -- you need both an `insert` and an `update` trigger, for instance.

Comment: Thank you for your response. How would I address this if the column already existed, could it be used with a CONSTRAINT on creation of the table?

Comment: @Lew_GreenGrass . . . I would drop the column and recreate it.  Populating it with a trigger has the "update" problem mentioned in the question.  Plus existing rows won't have the correct value.

Comment: Okay I see. So would I have to alter the table for every single entry, or just the once and from that point on it will do its things?

Comment: @Lew_GreenGrass . . . The beauty of a virtual column is that it is always up-to-date.  And it incurs no overhead on `inserts`.  And it doesn't (in and of itself) impose any locking.